# Result of attempting to create an object of an abstract class

Tags: java, reflection

What will line 5 (marked in the code) of the following program return?

```
abstract class AbstractClass{}

public class CreateAbstractClassObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("AbstractClass").newInstance(); // line 5
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Abstract classes are not instantiable by _definition_. What if you explained what you need instead?

Comment: line 5 won't actually _return_ anything...

Comment: It has hard to know what you are trying to achieve since others have stated, an abstract class cannot be instantiated. You should read up on abstraction, interfaces and inheritance as these will most likely allow you to implement whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: This was asked in a quiz, so curious to know if it all possible to create a instance of a abstract class

Comment: Compile and run it and see.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AbstractClass
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)

Comment: Did you run it with both classes in the default (empty) package.  If  not you'll have to add the package name to line 5, to avoid ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @Keith yes, I missed that, thanks                    java.lang.InstantiationException
 at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't return anything. An InstantiationException will be caught in line 6

There can't be an instance of an abstract class. Read java basics...